# how to define observation and action space for an array like input

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am working on a problem and I want to implement it as a reinforcement learning problem and integrate it into OpenAI gym. My states are in the form of lists of length n which each element is chosen from a discrete interval [0, m].
for example for n=6 and m=3, this is a sample from the observation space:

```
[0 2 1 3 3 2]
```

and the possible accessible states from this space is a set of other lists which are achieved by changing a number of k elements the elements in the list with a number from the same [0, m].
for example, for k=1 we can have the following states as two subsequent states of the previous state:

```
[0 2 2 3 3 2]
```

or

```
[0 3 1 3 3 2]
```

My question is that what is an efficient way to represent the "actions" in the OpenAI gym for such a scenario?

One way that come to my mind is to just use the next state as the action itself, for example, if I write:

```
action = env.action_space.sample()
```

the action would be the next state (which also implicitly contains the action) and then in the `env.step(action)` make the state equal to the next state.

Does anyone know a better way or using the implicit action representation with the next state is the optimal way?
Does anyone know a predefined gym environment that also has the same representation?
what are the cons of the implicit representation of the actions that I just explained?